# Open File with Non ASCII Characters

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unicode

I am trying to compute **SHA-256** of file. I have the following code that gives correct value of Checksum when the path is valid ie. It is ASCII. I have the following code:

```
#include <openssl\evp.h>
#include <sys\stat.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
const int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
std::string FileChecksum(std::string, std::string);

long long int GetFileSize(std::string filename)
{
    struct _stat64 stat_buf;
    int rc = _stat64(filename.c_str(), &stat_buf);
    return rc == 0 ? stat_buf.st_size : -1;
}

std::string fname = "D:\\Private\\Test\\asdf.txt"; // Need to support this D:\\Private\\Test\\सर्वज्ञ पन्त.txt

int main()
{
    std::string checksum = FileChecksum(fname , "sha256");
    std::cout << checksum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


static std::string FileChecksum(std::string file_path, std::string algorithm="sha256")
{
    EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;
    const EVP_MD *md;
    unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    int i;
    unsigned int md_len;

    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
    md = EVP_get_digestbyname(algorithm.c_str());

    if(!md) {
        printf("Unknown message digest %s\n",algorithm);
        return "";
    }

    mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
    std::ifstream readfile(file_path,std::ifstream::binary);
    if(!readfile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "COuldnot open file\n";
        return "";
    }
    readfile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    long long filelen = readfile.tellg();
    std::cout << "LEN IS " << filelen << std::endl;
    readfile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    if(filelen == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Return Null \n";
        return "";
    }

    EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL);
    long long temp_fil = filelen;
    while(!readfile.eof() && readfile.is_open() && temp_fil>0)
    {

        int bufferS = (temp_fil < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) ? temp_fil : MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;
        char *buffer = new char[bufferS+1];
        buffer[bufferS] = 0;
        readfile.read(buffer, bufferS);
        EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, buffer, bufferS);
        temp_fil -= bufferS;
        delete[] buffer;
    }
    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, md_value, &md_len);
    EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);
    char str[128] = { 0 };
    char *ptr = str;
    std::string ret;
    for(i = 0; i < md_len; i++)
    {
    //_snprintf(checksum_msg+cx,md_len-cx,"%02x",md_value[i]);
        sprintf(ptr,"%02x", md_value[i]);
        ptr += 2;
    }

    ret = str;
    /* Call this once before exit. */
    EVP_cleanup();
    return ret;
}
```

The code will give correct checksum of files with valid name. But once non-ascii character files are given, the program fails. I used **std::wstring** and it seems to fix the issue but the site [here](http://utf8everywhere.org/#how) discourages to use **std::wstring** by saying ***Do not use wchar_t or std::wstring in any place other than adjacent point to APIs accepting UTF-16.*** If I were to follow this, how do I make this code work for all types of path. I am using VS2010.

Comment: You don't need `in` for an `ifstream`. It's aready "in".

Comment: Yep. Its silly mistake.

Comment: this seems like a 'point adjacent to APIs accepting UTF-16' so std::wstring sounds good

Comment: What are the scenarios on when I should prefer **std::wstring** over **std::string** ?

Comment: Nitpick: don't select the algorithm by string parameter, use an enum or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wchar_t` is not portable across multiple platforms, as it is 2 bytes (UTF-16) on some platforms (Windows) but is 4 bytes (UTF-32) on other platforms (Linux, etc).  That is what the [site](http://utf8everywhere.org) is warning you about.

In your particular case, you are only focusing on Windows, so `std::wstring` is perfectly fine to use, since it uses UTF-16, which is the same encoding that the Win32 API uses all over the place.  What you are looking for is Microsoft's `_wstat64()` function, and Microsoft's non-standard `std::ifstream` constructor that accepts a  `wchar_t*` filename:

```
long long int GetFileSize(std::wstring filename)
{
    struct _stat64 stat_buf;
    int rc = _wstat64(filename.c_str(), &stat_buf);
    return rc == 0 ? stat_buf.st_size : -1;
}
```

```
std::wstring file_path = L"D:\\Private\\Test\\सर्वज्ञ पन्त.txt";

...

static std::string FileChecksum(std::wstring file_path, std::string algorithm="sha256")
{
    ...
    std::ifstream readfile(file_path.c_str(), std::ifstream::binary);
    ...
}
```

That being said, your `FileChecksum()` function is more complicated then it needs to be, it is not cleaning up correctly if an error occurs, it is not validating that `std::ifstream::read()` is actually reading as many bytes as you requested (it could read less), and it is misusing `std::ifstream::eof()`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <openssl\evp.h>
#include <sys\stat.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

const int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
std::string FileChecksum(std::wstring file_path, std::string algorithm = "sha256");

std::wstring fname = L"D:\\Private\\Test\\सर्वज्ञ पन्त.txt";

int main()
{
    std::string checksum = FileChecksum(fname, "sha256");
    std::cout << checksum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

std::string FileChecksum(std::wstring file_path, std::string algorithm)
{
    EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx = NULL;
    const EVP_MD *md;
    unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    unsigned int md_len;
    std::ostringstream oss;
    std::string ret;

    std::ifstream readfile(file_path.c_str(), std::ifstream::binary);
    if (readfile.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open file\n";
        goto finished;
    }

    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

    md = EVP_get_digestbyname(algorithm.c_str());    
    if (!md) {
        std::cout << "Unknown message digest " << algorithm << "\n";
        goto cleanup;
    }

    mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
    if (!mdctx) {
        std::cout << "Could not create context for message digest " << algorithm << "\n";
        goto cleanup;
    }

    EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL);

    do
    {
        readfile.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if ((readfile.fail()) && (!readfile.eof()))
        {
            std::cout << "Could not read from file\n";
            goto cleanup;
        }

        EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, buffer, readfile.gcount());
    }
    while (!readfile.eof());

    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, md_value, &md_len);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < md_len; i++)
        oss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int) md_value[i];
    ret = oss.str();

cleanup:
    if (mdctx) EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);
    EVP_cleanup();

finished:
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't a do must follow a while. **While** seems to be missing. I have to make this code cross-platform. The code should get the checksum of file in both windows and linux.

Comment: Yes, it was missing a `while`, I have fixed it now.  Unfortunately, different platforms handle file paths differently, in different encodings (Windows uses UTF-16, *Nix uses UTF-8, etc), different formats, etc. So you will have to account for that with some amount of platform-specific code wrapped in `#ifdef` statements, unless you use a third-party library that already does that work for you.

Comment: The code could not compute the correct checksum. When run under debugger, code reads file data into buffer and if the content is less than size of buffer, there is residue in buffer. eg like `sdasÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ` because of not having terminating character.

Comment: Check again..  `gcount()` returns the actual number of bytes places in the buffer by `read()`.  There is no "residue in buffer" being passed to `EVP_DigestUpdate()`.  As for `!` returning true, I forgot that `read()` sets both `failbit` and `eofbit` when it reaches EOF.  I have updated the code to account for that.

Comment: The code now seems to work but now computes wrong checksum. It does supports non-ascii path but computed SHA-256 is wrong.

Comment: Upon debugging I found that the `ï»¿`, which is a BOM for Unicode files. I think this is what causing the program to give wrong checksum of file. How can I fix this?

Comment: A hash operates on binary data, not on text. A hash of a file should take the *entire raw bytes* of the file into account as-is, regardless of what the content actually is. If you have to skip a BOM to get a hash for textual data, then I really have to question what you are trying to accomplish in the first place, because this is not how hashes should be used. How do you know the hash you are generating is wrong? What are you comparing it to? An ASCII file path vs a Unicode file pathhas no effect whatsoever on the content of the file.

Comment: I know hash is calculated upon binary data, but my previous code gives correct hash of any file. The modified code doesn't give correct sha256. You could validate it with online tools to compute SHA256.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78968/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-sarvagya-pant).